# Clonezilla failed to clone restore partition/resize issue

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone, clonezilla

I'm trying to clone a Windows 10 Home system (250Gb SSD) on another larger SSD (480Gb) I tought I should have no issues given source/destination sizes but when the cloning finished I've been reported errors in cloning sda3 partition (the restore partition I guess). Windows 10 *copy* now boots correctly and computer/disk management report this state:

[image: e]

The third partition is reported as healthy but I'm not sure about this given the errors reported in the cloning process. Moreover if I try to start the recovery process from withing Windows it complains about no recovery source and suggest to use install media.
Besides this I wish to resize the main partition (*C:* unit) to take all the free space but with the current partitions layout is impossible (for me).
To cut it short:

1. How can I check for the restore partition to be really working?
2. How can I rebuild the restore partition if it's not working?
3. How can I resize *C:* to collect all the free space (of course I need to *move* the restore partition on the *leftmost* part of the disk).

Comment: Why do you use Linux tools on Windows disk? Use for example [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) to do [Disk Clone](https://www.backup-utility.com/help/disk-clone.html).

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: AOMEI hanged for 3 hours on 34% ... :-(

Comment: I start to think that there are bad sectors on the disk.

Comment: Yeah maybe in the recovery partition...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "recovery", but perhaps [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html) will help. For part 3, I don't know what is the "Integro" is, but can it be moved by a partition editor to the *right-most* position so unallocated space follows C?

Comment: Integro means Healthy but It's a fake diagnosis I think.

Comment: I can remove the failed recovery partition resize the main partition and create a new recovery *by hand*. I wa wondering if there was  a more straightforward way.

Comment: Can it be moved, or is this blocked by a bad sector? If it can be moved then all is ok. Otherwise, you have a problem that may hit when you integrate the unallocated space into C, and the solution then can be to make the unallocated space into a new partition D, leaving the bad partition in place.